# CollectionView not reloading after retrieving data from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been able to retrieve data from Firestore but my collection is not reloading even after running the "collectionview.reload" method on the main thread. The collectionview works when I input the data manually but returns 0 when I try to populate it with data from Firestone. Please help!

Below is the code for the api call:

```
func loadRooms() {
        roomName = []
//        print("RoomName Count = ", roomName.count)
       

        db.collection("rooms").getDocuments { querysnapshot, error in
            if let e = error {
                print("Unable to load data, \(e)")
            } else {
                if let snapshotDocuments = querysnapshot?.documents {
                    for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                        let data = doc.data()
                        print(data)
                        if let room = data["roomNameLabel"] as? String, let roomDescription = data["roomNameDescription"] as? String, let dateRoomCreated = data["dateCreated"] as? Double {
                            let newRoomDetails = NewRoom(roomNameLabel: room, roomNameDescription: roomDescription, dateCreated: dateRoomCreated)
                            
                            self.roomName.append(newRoomDetails)
                            

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.collectionview.reloadData()
                            
                            }
                            

                            


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is the code for collectionview

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("room count = ", roomName.count)

        return roomName.count
    }
    
    
    
    
    //collectionView for the roomPills that holds each roomName created by the user
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let roomCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NavReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! NavRoomCell

        roomCell.NavRoomLabel.text = roomName[indexPath.row].roomNameLabel

        return roomCell
    }
```

Below is my viewdidload

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    
        tableview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate = self
        
        
        tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
        collectionview.register(UINib(nibName: "NavRoomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "NavReusableCell")
        
   
        loadRooms()
        
    }
```

[image: console returning 0 when I run the code]

Below is the output of the print(data) line

["roomNameDescription": After a long absence, "dateCreated": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1671137642 nanoseconds=920900000>, "roomNameLabel": brandNew Room]
["roomNameDescription": Man Dem 2, "dateCreated": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1661365735 nanoseconds=82324000>, "roomNameLabel": Awon Omo Ologo]
["roomNameDescription": Man Dem Again o, "dateCreated": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1661353330 nanoseconds=367393000>, "roomNameLabel": Benefit Boys]
["roomNameDescription": Man Dem, "dateCreated": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1661353300 nanoseconds=656065000>, "roomNameLabel": City Boys]

Comment: What actually happens inside `loadRooms`? Why do you call `reloadData` inside the `for` loop instead of after the loop?

Comment: loadRooms retrieve data from my FIrestore then appends it to an array which is suppose to be the datasource of the collectionview. I'm calling the reloadData after appending my array with new data

Comment: I can see that is what the code is supposed to do. I'm asking what actually happens when you run the code. What debugging have you done? Is the call to `reloadData` actually reached during runtime? If so, does the array actually have any values in it? Are your collection view data source methods being called at all? If so, do they return expected values or not?

Comment: The collectionview data source method is being called but doesn't return any value. I've update the question with a print statement that shows the array return 0.

Comment: What about print statements from loadRooms? Use the debugger and see what is actually happening.

Comment: The roomName array is turning up empty. For some reasons I don't know the  self.roomName.append(newRoomDetails) is not working

Comment: Is the long `if let` statement before the `self.roomName.append(newRoomDetails)` line being reached? If so then clearly one of the values is `nil` or the wrong type. Update your question with the output of the `print(data)` line (as text, not as a picture).

Comment: I've updated the question with the output. I don't think that line is being reached because the print statements I have before `self.roomName.append(newRoomDetails)` is not bring out any output @HangarRash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line:

```
if let room = data["roomNameLabel"] as? String,
   let roomDescription = data["roomNameDescription"] as? String,
   let dateRoomCreated = data["dateCreated"] as? Double {
```

But look at the output of `print(data)` for the `dateCreated` value:

> "dateCreated": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1671137642 nanoseconds=920900000>

The value is an instance of `FIRTimestamp` but you are trying to cast it as a `Double`. This cast is failing so the whole `if let` statement is false. This is why you never append any values to `self.roomName`.

Update your `if let` statement by changing `as? Double` to `as? FIRTimestamp`. Then use whatever API `FIRTimestamp` provides to get the desired `Double` value from it where you create the `NewRoom` instance.

I have no experience with Firebase so you will need to lookup those specific details.

---

And to reiterate earlier comments - you should move the call to reload the collection view to after the `for` loop. It makes no sense to call `reloadData` for each loop iteration. Just call it once after fully updating the array.

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so much!!!!! It's working perfectly now! I wish I could upvote your answer a million times!!

Answer (score 0):

Call it after the end point of the for loop.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

   self.collectionview.reloadData()
                            
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the issue posted in the question? Yes, `reloadData` should only be called once after the loop but the question states the collection view shows no data. Simply moving the call to `reloadData` isn't going to fix that. Clearly there is another issue.

Comment: Oh I didn't see. There may be 2 problems. I can't say for sure because I didn't run the code.
1) It cannot add the newRoomDetails data it receives from the service into the roomName array.
2) It looks like there may be an error in the register of tableView and collectionView.

I wish we could see the class completely.

Comment: After using print statements, I've discovered that it's just not adding newRoomDetails data to the array and I don't know why. Any suggestions as to why this is the case?